# How to enable NuGet restore on TeamCity Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: .net, linux, mono, continuous-integration, teamcity

**Question**. What should I do to enable *NuGet Installer* step in *TeamCity* on *Ubuntu Linux*? Is it possible at all?

**What I have now**. *TeamCity 9.1.6* runs on *Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Linux*. There is a build agent. Its configuration defines

```
env.MSBuild=/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/12.0/bin
env.DotNetFramework4.5_x86=/usr/lib/mono/4.5
```

The build configuration contains *NuGet Installer* step (to restore packages). And there is a list of incompatible agents for this configuration, which contains the specified build agent with following message:

```
Incompatible runner: NuGet Installer
Unmet requirements: Exists=>DotNetFramework(4.5|4.5.1|4.5.2|4.6|4.6.1)_x86 exists
```

That's it. This agent is not being launched (of course). And I feel lack of knowledge necessary to investigate this problem further. E. g. why does the word "exist" appears twice in the "Unmet requirements" section; or how to make *Mono* and *MS .NET Framework* friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Workaround**. After a while I have implemented the following workaround. I have disabled the *NuGet Installer* step at all and introduced a new step of type *Command Line*. Its configuration:

```
Run: Custom script
Custom script: mono --runtime=v4.0 ~/nuget.exe restore %teamcity.build.workingDir%/MySolution.sln
```

One should replace the given parameters with his own, of course.

I'll appreciate the answer with the native *TeamCity*'s *NuGet Installer* step.